# Inserting external content into bootsrap modal

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I am aware that similiar questions have been asked, but I have not found anything that specifically answers my question. I have created a calculator that looks like this: https://benisburgers.github.io/calculator/.

I would like to embed this calculator into the modal on my portfolio (https://benisburgers.github.io/portfolio/), so that if somebody clicks on the picture of the calculator, the calculator becomes directly accessible within the modal.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Best regards

Beni

Comment: You inject your calculator html structure in the modal container and activate any event listeners for your calculator after you inject your calculator html.

Comment: Thank you. How do I deal with the CSS file in the best way possible? Do I create a second seperate css file?

Comment: If your calc cas is not that large you can mix it with your other custom css just to avoid extra browser request.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. See www.benibargera.com

Comment: Great! yup I saw it. great app!